# PrimeVue Dropdown: use command callback to assign value

Tags: vuejs3, dropdown, primevue

I am using the Dropdown component to allow users toggle between two views.
This works fine. Both views contains forms the users can interact with.
Now, i need to implement a "Changes unsaved, do you want to leave" dialog when a user changes the view mode using the dropdown. Thus, i added a command: () => {} to the options for the dropdown.

However, the v-model is changed regardless of the logic in the command callback.
I then used a  within the dropdown and used the click event to call the callback. This approach
calls the callback function but the v-model still changes even when the callback does not change it.

Has anyone done anything similar to this? Is there a better way of doing this?

Snippet:

```
<Dropdown
 v-model="mode"
 :options="modeOptions"
 optionLabel="name"
 optionValue="value"
 placeholder="Select Mode"
 size="small"
>
 <template #option="slotProps">
  <div class="flex" @click="slotProps.option.command">
    <div>{{ slotProps.option.name }}</div>
   </div>
 </template>
</Dropdown>


//script
const mode = ref('student')
const isEditing = ref(true)
const modeOptions = [
 {
  name: 'Student',
  value: 'student',
  command: () => {
   if(isEditing.value){ 
    //block mode changing
   }else{
    mode.value = 'student'
    }
   }
  },
   {
  name: 'Teacher',
  value: 'teacher',
  command: () => {
   if(isEditing.value){ 
    //block mode changing
   }else{
    mode.value = 'teacher'
    }
   }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to achieve my goal by removing the v-model prop from Dropdown.
And then to give visuals on the active mode, i pass the mode to the placeholder instead. Hope this helps others.

```
<Dropdown
 :options="modeOptions"
 optionLabel="name"
 optionValue="value"
 :placeholder="mode"
 size="small"
>
 <template #option="slotProps">
  <div class="flex" @click="slotProps.option.command">
    <div>{{ slotProps.option.name }}</div>
   </div>
 </template>
</Dropdown>
```

Doing this prevents vue and the component (i'm not sure which) from automatically assigning the selected option to the mode variable.

Answer (score 0):

you put your `@click` on the option so when it's clicked the dropdown does its job and don't think about your function.
put `@click` on your dropdown and then check if the value you want is clicked or not then do what you want and don't forget that if you don't want to change the v-model, set it to your previous value

```
<script setup>
function onClickHandler() {
... #other conditions and functions
mode.command()
... #other conditions and functions
#if needed you can set your mode in here
}
</setup>

<Dropdown
v-model="mode"
 :options="modeOptions"
 optionLabel="name"
 optionValue="value"
 :placeholder="mode"
 size="small"
@click="onClickHandler"
>
 <template #option="slotProps">
  <div class="flex" >
    <div>{{ slotProps.option.name }}</div>
   </div>
 </template>
</Dropdown>
```